# How to write a partitioned parquet file in apache beam java

Tags: apache-beam, parquet, apache-beam-io

I am new to Apache Beam and not sure how to accomplish this task.
I want to write a partitioned parquet file using Apache Beam in Java.
Data is read from Kafka and I want the file to have a new partition every hour. The timestamp columns is present in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [FixedWindows](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#fixed-time-windows) for that. There is an example of [windowed WordCount](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/WindowedWordCount.java) that writes every window into separate text file - so, I believe, it can be adapted for your case.